# How to limit validation to a particular trigger?

Tags: asp.net, validation, events, triggers, controls

Is there any way to limit the validation of a validator control to a particular event or trigger? Say, I want my validator1 to be activated only when button1 was clicked, and validator2 to be activated only when button2 was clicked. How can I do this in asp.net?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ValidationGroups](http://%5B1%5D:%20h://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) are what you're looking for(ASP.NET >= 2.0)

> Validation groups allow you to organize validation controls on a page
>   as a set. Each validation group can perform validation independently
>   from other validation groups on the page.

```
<asp:textbox id="AgeTextBox" 
  runat="Server">
</asp:textbox>

&nbsp;

<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"
  controltovalidate="AgeTextBox"
  validationgroup="PersonalInfoGroup"
  errormessage="Enter your age."
  runat="Server">
</asp:requiredfieldvalidator>

<br /><br />

<!--When Button1 is clicked, only validation
controls that are a part of PersonalInfoGroup
are validated.-->
<asp:button id="Button1" 
  text="Validate" 
  causesvalidation="true"
  validationgroup="PersonalInfoGroup"
  runat="Server" />

<br /><br />

<asp:textbox id="CityTextBox" 
  runat="Server">
</asp:textbox>

&nbsp;

<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator2"
  controltovalidate="CityTextBox"
  validationgroup="LocationInfoGroup"
  errormessage="Enter a city name."
  runat="Server">
</asp:requiredfieldvalidator>

<br /><br />

<!--When Button2 is clicked, only validation
controls that are a part of LocationInfoGroup
are validated.-->
<asp:button id="Button2" 
  text="Validate" 
  causesvalidation="true"
  validationgroup="LocationInfoGroup"
  runat="Server" />
```