# Handling multiple buttons in same asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

hello everyone i am using two buttons on same asp.net webpage.both contain different codes
first button fetches the data from database here is the code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = Request.QueryString["username"];
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=swa1;User Id=swa1;Password=swa1;");
    conn.Open();

    try 
    {
        string checkaddress = "select address,city,zipcode from regforswa where username=" + username;
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkaddress, conn);
        using (var reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var tmp = reader["address"];
                if (tmp != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    laddress.Visible = true;
                    laddress.Text = reader["address"].ToString();
                }
                var cty = reader["city"];
                if (cty != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    lcity.Visible = true;
                    lcity.Text = reader["city"].ToString();
                }
                var zip = reader["zipcode"];
                if (zip != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    lzipcode.Visible = true;
                    lzipcode.Text = reader["zipcode"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

second button updates the value in the database using textbox values here is the code

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = Request.QueryString["username"];
    string address=TextBox4.Text;
    string city=TextBox5.Text;
    string zipcode=TextBox6.Text;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=swa1;User Id=swa1;Password=swa1;");
    conn.Open();

    try 
    {
        string updateaddress = "UPDATE regforswa SET address=@address,city=@city,zipcode=@zipcode WHERE username="+username;
       SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(updateaddress, conn);
       com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address",address);
       com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city",city);
       com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zipcode",zipcode);
       // com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",username);
       if (com.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
       {
           result.Visible = true;
           result.Text = "congradulations.your address has been changed";
       }
       else
       {
           result.Visible = true;
           result.Text = "sorry please try again"; 
       }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

but the problem is when i hit the first button the validation controls related to second button does not allow the page to be reloaded so i can not fetch the data.

my question is can we use two buttons on same webpage but with different functionality to perform?

Comment: I think you should put them in different `<form>`s.

Comment: I assume that you are using [tag:webforms]. Is this the case?
This [question may be of use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555464/how-to-limit-validation-to-a-particular-trigger/8555489#8555489)

Comment: Try `url?=username=username;DROP DATABASE swa` and learn how to avoid SQL injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use "Validation groups" to fix your problem. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424(v=vs.100).aspx